# How to randomise a complete Data Frame with Normal Probability Distribution for Simulation in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

How to create a new dataframe from an existing data frame by randomizing the values with average as original respective value and 20% standard deviation in python?
I want to create a new dataframe by randomizing all the values such that if the original value of a particular entry is x, the value of that entry is randomized with 20% standard deviation and the average of this normal probability distribution must be the original entry x.

This process should repeat 10,000 times to perform simulation by taking one randomly generated dataframe at a time.

Eg:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00ix4.png)
If this is the existing data frame, how to randomize its values with python code?

I have tried using

1. np.random.normal(avg, std_dev, num_reps) and
2. df.applymap(np.random.normal(avg, std_dev, num_reps)

but none takes original dataframe values as average(avg)

Comment: What efforts have you put in to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to calculate mean for every column and generate new values for it accordingly:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [0, 15, 18, 30, 0, 20],
                            'b': [0, 15, 18, 30, 0, 20]})
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

    for col_name in df.columns:
        values = df[col_name]
        mean = np.mean(values)
        std = 0.2 * mean
        new_values = np.random.normal(mean, std, len(values))
        new_df[col_name] = new_values
```